# Extract online specific value from JSON

Tags: php, json

Hello I have a script which gets the JSON output in an array but I want to extract only the name field. It is acutally HostBill API, and I just want to print the domain TLDs. I tried all the ways but I am getting this error
**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\hostbill\check\index.php on line 22**

I don't know whats wrong with the code.

My required Output is:
Product Name: ".com";
Which comes from this JSON as this
"name": ".com",

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
   $url = 'http://localhost/hostbill/admin/api.php';
   $post = array(
      'api_id' => '4c76ed9e1d48cc4f5d56',
      'api_key' => '2056c9b03cc95ce625b1',
      'call' => 'getProducts',
      'id'=>1
   );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $return = json_decode($data, true);
   print_r($return);
   $product_name = $return->name;
   echo "Product Name: ".$product_name;
?>
```

Hostbill JSON Response Sample:

```
   {
      "success": true,
      "products": {
         "236": {
            "id": "236",
            "type": "9",
            "name": "VPS-1024-w-sliders",
            "stock": "0",
            "paytype": "Free",
            "description": "",
            "m_setup": "0.00",
            "q_setup": "0.00",
            "s_setup": "0.00",
            "a_setup": "0.00",
            "b_setup": "0.00",
            "t_setup": "0.00",
            "d_setup": "0.00",
            "w_setup": "0.00",
            "h_setup": "0.00",
            "m": "30.00",
            "q": "0.00",
            "a": "0.00",
            "s": "0.00",
            "b": "0.00",
            "t": "0.00",
            "d": "0.00",
            "w": "0.00",
            "h": "0.00",
            "qty": "0",
            "visible": "1",
            "ptype": "onappcloud",
            "accounts": "1"
         },
         "235": {
            "id": "235",
            "type": "9",
            "name": "VPS-512-w-sliders",
            "stock": "0",
            "paytype": "Regular",
            "description": "",
            "m_setup": "0.00",
            "q_setup": "0.00",
            "s_setup": "0.00",
            "a_setup": "0.00",
            "b_setup": "0.00",
            "t_setup": "0.00",
            "d_setup": "0.00",
            "w_setup": "0.00",
            "h_setup": "0.00",
            "m": "20.00",
            "q": "0.00",
            "a": "0.00",
            "s": "0.00",
            "b": "0.00",
            "t": "0.00",
            "d": "0.00",
            "w": "0.00",
            "h": "0.00",
            "qty": "0",
            "visible": "1",
            "ptype": "onappcloud",
            "accounts": "3"
         }
      },
      "call": "getProducts",
      "server_time": 1317712858
   }
```

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($return);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Products are in `array`, so use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over all products.

```
foreach($return['products'] AS $product){
    echo "Product Name: ".$product['name'];
}
```

You should also check if API response is valid. If API dosen't respond with array of products or responds with empty response, you would get error. This would do it.

```
if(isset($return['products']) && is_array($return['products'])){
    foreach($return['products'] AS $product){
        echo "Product Name: ".$product['name'];
    }
}
```

**Extract only specific category**

To get only certain products, just use `if` statement. For example to get products from `category_id` `1` and `type` `9`:

```
foreach($return['products'] AS $product){
    if($product['category_id'] == 1 && $product['type'] == 9){
        echo "Product Name: ".$product['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but is it possible to extract only from a specific category? in JSON there are two fields 1 is type and second is category_id

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: category_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\hostbill\check\index.php on line 22

Comment: This is just example. You said you have field named `category_id`. In `array` there is no such field, replace `category_id` with field name, what contains real category ID.

Comment: OK my mistake sorry rest every thing works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error because it is not an object. It's an array.

So it should be:

```
 foreach($return['products'] as $key => $product){
  echo "Product Name: ".  $product['name'];
 }
```